# Get VID/PID of the connected usb devices through VBScript

Tags: vbscript, usb, device

I'm looking for a VBScript which can store VID/PID of connected USB devices in a variable. So What is the VBScript for doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get it by using WMI but there isn't a dynamic class for connected USB devices in WMI.
Need to some relation info usb devices with plugged devices to get plugged ones.
So, consider this example:

```
Option Explicit
Dim oWMISrv, collDvcs, collUSBDvcs, iUSBDvc , iDvc, sDvcID, sPID, sVID

Function ReplaceX(ByVal sValue, ByVal sPattern, ByVal sNValue)
    Dim oReg : Set oReg = New RegExp
    oReg.Pattern = sPattern
    ReplaceX = oReg.Replace(sValue, sNValue)
    Set oReg = Nothing
End Function

Set oWMISrv = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set collDvcs = oWMISrv.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice")

For Each iDvc In collDvcs
    If InStr(iDvc.Dependent, "VID_") Then ' Except keychain drives

        sDvcID = ReplaceX(iDvc.Dependent, ".*""(.*)""", "$1")
        sPID = ReplaceX(sDvcID, ".*PID_([^\\]*).*", "$1")
        sVID = ReplaceX(sDvcID, ".*VID_([^&]*).*", "$1")

        Set collUSBDvcs = oWMISrv.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * From Win32_PnPEntity Where DeviceID = '" & sDvcID & "'")
        For Each iUSBDvc in collUSBDvcs
            Wscript.Echo "Name : "& iUSBDvc.Description
            Wscript.Echo "VID : "& sVID
            Wscript.Echo "PID : "& sPID
            Wscript.Echo String(50, "-")
        Next
        Set collUSBDvcs = Nothing

    End If
Next

Set collDvcs = Nothing
Set oWMISrv = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, But really looking for a script which only show VIP/PID of connected devices, yours help me a lot and I should say thank you :)